# Formula 1 Database - Can't get the points awarding system to work

Tags: sql, sql-server

I guess that by the title of this question you already know what my problem is.

Since last week, I've been stuck on this part and I just can't seem to find a solution for it.

Here's my code:

```
CREATE TABLE Grand_Prix(
ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
Name VARCHAR(45),
Data_GP DATE,
Points INTEGER,
Position INTEGER,
Track_id INTEGER REFERENCES Track(ID),
Country_id INTEGER REFERENCES Country(ID),
Driver_id INTEGER REFERENCES Driver(ID)
)
```

That's my Table for the Grand Prix, where the points and positions are in, then I do some Inserts, like these:

```
INSERT INTO Grande_Premio(Name, Data_GP, Track_id, Country_id, Driver_id, Position)
VALUES ('Gulf Air Bahrain Grand Prix', '03/26/2021', 1, 13, 1, 20),
('Gulf Air Bahrain Grand Prix', '03/26/2021', 1, 13, 2, 16),
('Gulf Air Bahrain Grand Prix', '03/26/2021', 1, 13, 3, 18),
('Gulf Air Bahrain Grand Prix', '03/26/2021', 1, 13, 4, 14),
('Gulf Air Bahrain Grand Prix', '03/26/2021', 1, 13, 5, 11),
('Gulf Air Bahrain Grand Prix', '03/26/2021', 1, 13, 6, 12),
('Gulf Air Bahrain Grand Prix', '03/26/2021', 1, 13, 7, 9),
('Gulf Air Bahrain Grand Prix', '03/26/2021', 1, 13, 8, 17),
('Gulf Air Bahrain Grand Prix', '03/26/2021', 1, 13, 9, 15),
('Gulf Air Bahrain Grand Prix', '03/26/2021', 1, 13, 10, 10),
('Gulf Air Bahrain Grand Prix', '03/26/2021', 1, 13, 11, 13),
('Gulf Air Bahrain Grand Prix', '03/26/2021', 1, 13, 12, 19),
('Gulf Air Bahrain Grand Prix', '03/26/2021', 1, 13, 13, 7),
('Gulf Air Bahrain Grand Prix', '03/26/2021', 1, 13, 14, 4),
('Gulf Air Bahrain Grand Prix', '03/26/2021', 1, 13, 15, 8),
('Gulf Air Bahrain Grand Prix', '03/26/2021', 1, 13, 16, 6),
('Gulf Air Bahrain Grand Prix', '03/26/2021', 1, 13, 17, 5),
('Gulf Air Bahrain Grand Prix', '03/26/2021', 1, 13, 18, 2),
('Gulf Air Bahrain Grand Prix', '03/26/2021', 1, 13, 19, 3),
('Gulf Air Bahrain Grand Prix', '03/26/2021', 1, 13, 20, 1)
```

After that, I do an Update so that the drivers that finish in X position gets awarded X points:

```
UPDATE Grand_Prix
SET Points += 25
WHERE Position = 1

UPDATE Grand_Prix
SET Points += 18
WHERE Position = 2

UPDATE Grand_Prix
SET Points += 15
WHERE Position = 3

UPDATE Grand_Prix
SET Points += 12
WHERE Position = 4

UPDATE Grand_Prix
SET Points += 10
WHERE Position = 5

UPDATE Grand_Prix
SET Points += 8
WHERE Position = 6

UPDATE Grand_Prix
SET Points += 6
WHERE Position = 7

UPDATE Grand_Prix
SET Points += 4
WHERE Position = 8

UPDATE Grand_Prix
SET Points += 2
WHERE Position = 9

UPDATE Grand_Prix
SET Points += 1
WHERE Position = 10
```

Yet, after this, when I do Select on the Grand_Prix table, the Points still appear NULL, any idea why?

I am a bit new to SQL and to this website so I am sorry if I am not expressing myself well or I am just making a very basic mistake that I am not seeing.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: of course. NULL+25 is still NULL. Try UPDATE Grand_Prix
SET Points = 25
WHERE Position = 1

Comment: Better question is why calculate and store this value since it is entirely dependent on another column and a simple formula? A computed column would do this and always be correct.

Comment: What about whomever gets fastest lap or finishes in the top 3 in sprint qualifying? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression

```
update grand_prix
    set points += (case when position = 1 then 25
                        when position = 2 then 18
                        . . . 
                        else 0
                    end);
```